# Tomcat6 Eclipse3.5 on Ubuntu 11.04 not working together

Tags: jsp, ubuntu, http-status-code-404, tomcat6

I am using eclipse3.5 and tomcat6 on Ubuntu 11.04. 
I am trying to create Dynamic and website project (JSP) on Tomcat6 server but every time its giving me http 404 error (resources not found). I have created a new tomcat6 server and included the project in it, but when I run this project I am coming up with 404(http://localhost:8080/projectname/).
I followed every possible solution available on line. Changing the Catalina variable, installing and reinstalling tomcat6 manually, changing workspace and creating symbolic links and changing the permissions on file according to one of the thread [Ubuntu Forums link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1285925&highlight=eclipse%20tomcat%20404%20error)

Still no result....... 
I have given many hours to this only to get zero and frustrating results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing some code - `web.xml` fragments, servlet declarations, folder structure... _anything_

Comment: Now I have purge all tomcat6-* files. I havent made any changes to web.XML and I haven't created any jsp pages. I created a basic web project and I was trying to run it through tomcat6 server. I did create index.html page with "hello" in the body to see whether tomcat6 is working or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it come to setup Eclipse, Tomcat and Java there are many things that can go wrong. In this case Ubuntu 11.04 is providing Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo) and Tomcat6 as standard edition through Software Center or Synaptic pkg. or Aptitude. Therefor I was installing Eclipse and Tomcat as they were provided on Ubuntu standard repo. For some reason the Environment variables on Ubuntu were not setting properly so I tried and fixed the variable by placing those variable in system bash file and assigning them values manually:

vi ~/.bashrc

Using CATALINA_BASE: /usr/local/tomcat-6 dir

Using CATALINA_HOME: /usr/local/tomcat-6 dir

Using JRE_HOME: /usr/lib/j2sdk1.6-sun/

this is one way to do it or you can export these variable like in cmd line:

in bash: export JAVA_HOME=/path_to_j2sdk

(e.g. export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/j2sdk similarly for Catalina variable's)

In My case above solution was not working even though I invested couple of days it. 
I decided to purge (remove completely) the existing Tomcat6 and Eclispe3.5 and then installed I followed [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37822/how-do-i-install-apache-tomcat-7) and did same with Eclipse3.6.

1. Download Eclipse3.6 from [eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/indigo/SR1/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz) remember to download J2EE not JAVA for JSP.
2. tar -xzvf filename.tar.gz
3. I placed Tomcat7 and eclipse in the same folder /usr/local/java

   sudo mv Directory_Name(Extracted eg.eclipse /usr/local/java)

4.Check for ROOT Folder in org.eclipse.wst.server.core, Make sure that you replace (or rm -rf old ROOT then cp the new ROOT folder) this ROOT folder created by tomcat6 with new ROOT from tomcat7 because some time ubuntu11.04 do not replace this file by itself and this error will take lot of time to solve so follow these cmd in terminal make sure that you are sudo:

/home/local/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/ROOT

with /usr/local/java/apache-tomcat-7.0.22-src/webapps/ROOT

From here you can simply click on "eclipse" executable file in  /usr/local/java/eclipse and follow this [link](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Configuring_an_Application_Server_in_Eclipse.pdf) it is based on Tomcat5.5 but tomcat7 server setup in eclipse3.6 is exactly similar to this.

Leave your comments and questions.